# How to get the values from a range of cells in Google Sheets and compare the same with a predefined value to send mail if the condition mets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I was setting up an gooleappscript to automatically send mail if certain condition meets for a range o value in spreadsheet.I need to read values of multiple cells (A1 to A10) and check whether its less than 3 , if so then send a mail to mentioned mail id. I have done the script but its only reading value form the first cell and sends mail accordingly. My purpose is to read each selected cell values and then compare it . Any idea to correct it.

[Google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTsjj.jpg)

Below is the code am using.

```js
function sendMail() {
  if (SpreadsheetApp.openById('1bmAFWR7YsfMlgxExLKY4**********').getRange("A2:A10").getValue()<3) ;
  MailApp.sendEmail("s*****@gmail.com", "*Subject*******", "Dear Sreenath, Your **** is getting expired in two days !");
 }
```

i have tried `getRange("A2:A10").getValue()<3` but its reading and comparing the value from `A2` only.ie in this case only value 10 is read and compared.i need to read all values from `A2` to `A10` and check whether its less than 3. and if any one of it is less than 3 then need to trigger the send mail command.
Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to fix a few things:

`getValue()` gets just one value. You want all the values in the range. So use `getValues()`. [Ref doc here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).

The values you receive are an array. You'll need to loop through the array and check each value.

Note that this

> "Returns a two-dimensional array of values, indexed by row, then by
>   column"

You may also want to specify which sheet to get the values from.

So I would try something like this:

```
function sendMail() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1bmAFWR7YsfMlgxExLKY4**********'); // The spreadsheet

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("The_Name_Of_Your_Sheet_Goes_Here"); // The sheet that has the data

  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:A10").getValues(); // The values from the sheet

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // Loop throught the values

    if ( data[i][0] < 3 ) { // The array is a 2-d array. See ref doc in this post

      MailApp.sendEmail("s*****@gmail.com", "*Subject*******", "Dear Sreenath, Your **** is getting expired in two days !"); // Send email

    }

  }

}
```